# C# Database Blocking Threads bad for large amounts of clients

Tags: c#, mysql, multithreading, sockets, threadpool

### Info:

I have created a C# Console Server and WinForms Client for a buisness.

(Correct me if i'm wrong, I have done *a lot* of research. So I may have confused certain topics.)

On the server, I have read that using `Socket.BegingReceive` with an `AsyncCallback` Method is best. Due to the fact that it uses the `ThreadPool` class. Multi threading the clients while also reusing threads etc. (Instead of doing a while loop on a single threaded setup or a thread per client. (I have read that these have specific drawbacks I'm not interested in.))

Basically what I was striving for was to make sure that if the app i was making suddenly exploded and 100,000 (maybe even 1,000,000?!) people were using it at the same time that it would maintain good and stable connections for each client.

---

### Situation:

***The Server:*** Intel i5 4 Core: The server processes MYSQL requests on another server and serves it back to clients formatted in the way they would expect.

***The Client:*** Unlimited hardware resources: Asks the server for data when browsing the form to fill the form.

*So my fear:* Lets say 4 Clients connect and request the server process data that takes about 5 seconds to process the MYSQL database(of which, i know, is like a lifetime in processing speed. (Worst case scenario etc)). What if a 5th Client connects. That means that the ThreadPool would have to create another thread to hold this process. Now make these numbers larger, and I have 100 simultaneous Client request the exact long running method. On a 4 Core CPU. So now the ThreadPool is spending upwards of a ten or more seconds to create all these new threads.

---

### **Question:**

Edit: to narrow down question:

**How do i implement async programming for the FindPrimeNumbers call. (That method is searching a database (MySQL on a different server, if that helps) for numbers.)**

<strike>What do I do to prevent this from happening? How do I make this more intuitive. How do I prevent large loads from potentially creating bad user experiences, etc., etc.</strike>

---

### Sudo Code

The FindPrimerNumber method is like the database call.

```
class Program
{
    private static Socket serverSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
    private static List<Socket> clientSockets = new List<Socket>();
    private static CancellationTokenSource CancelSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
    private static CancellationToken CancelToken = CancelSource.Token;
    private const int BUFFER_SIZE = 2048;
    private const int PORT = 100;
    private static readonly byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];

    static void Main()
    {
        SetupServer();
        Console.ReadLine();
        CloseAllSockets();
    }

    private static void SetupServer()
    {
        serverSocket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, PORT));
        serverSocket.Listen(0);
        serverSocket.BeginAccept(BeginAcceptCallback, null);
    }

    private static void CloseAllSockets()
    {
        foreach (Socket socket in clientSockets)
        {
            socket.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
            socket.Close();
        }

        serverSocket.Close();
    }

    private static void BeginAcceptCallback(IAsyncResult AR)
    {
        Socket socket = serverSocket.EndAccept(AR);
        clientSockets.Add(socket);
        socket.BeginReceive(buffer, 0, BUFFER_SIZE, SocketFlags.None, BeginReceiveCallback, socket);
        Console.WriteLine("Client connected!");
        serverSocket.BeginAccept(BeginAcceptCallback, null);
    }

    private static void BeginReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult AR)
    {
        Socket current = (Socket)AR.AsyncState;
        int receivedInt = current.EndReceive(AR);
        byte[] received = new byte[receivedInt];
        Array.Copy(buffer, received, receivedInt);

        current.BeginReceive(buffer, 0, BUFFER_SIZE, SocketFlags.None, BeginReceiveCallback, current);

        string text = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(received);
        int number = 0;
        if (text.ToLower() == "exit")
        {
            current.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
            current.Close();
            clientSockets.Remove(current);
            Console.WriteLine("Client Disconnected");
            return;
        }
        else if (int.TryParse(text, out number))
        {
            int num = FindPrimeNumber(number);
            byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(num.ToString());
            current.Send(data);
            Console.WriteLine("Prime Number: "+num+" :Sent");
        }
        else
        {
            current.Send(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Not a Command"));
        }
    }

    //VERY LONG CPU FUNCTION
    public static int FindPrimeNumber(int n)
    {
        //Connect to database (MySQL Database on a different server, if that makes a difference)
        //Send Query
        //Read Return
        return queryReturn()
    }
}
```

Comment: There are so many things / places where you could be going wrong in regards to your code in reference to `Object creation` Releasing..etc.. very hard for anyone to definitively answer this without even seeing your code..

Comment: Just make your SQL requests async. Also, you misunderstood how threads in thread pool manage code execution.

Comment: @eocron, that didn't occur to me. Ill have to do additional research on that. Thank you for the quick thought.

Comment: Not everything binded to CPU, almost always the main reason relays at communication, which don't need much CPU time, so, as long as everything asynced and not waiting response in sync - all good, and you need to worry only about your hardware.

Comment: Yes, the biggest enemy of a webserver that scales to a large number of users is blocking threads. Any blocking code should be replaced with the `async/await` equivalent. W.r.t. Using APM `BeginXXX`, `EndXXX` pairs, you should also consider a move towards TAP APIs instead (i.e. Task-based APIs that support `async/await`). Your code will be cleaner, and these have more-or-less the same performance characteristics as the APM APIs that you mention in your post, with the advantage of considerably less cognitive load.

Comment: ...so any time you have code that blocks, such as synchronous IO, `Thread.Sleep`, waits on semaphores etc, these should be replaced with the `async await` Task-based equivalents.

Comment: If you are absolutely religious about avoiding blocking code, there's really no reason for your ThreadPool to require more than a few threads. I've serviced thousands of concurrent clients with the CPU virtually idling on a typical CRUD app. It rarely needed to spin up more than the default number of threads.

Comment: The biggest "real-life issue with scalability" I've dealt with is not setting up a good set of axioms: that is, having not designing operations such that can be safely run in parallel or sharded or programming for consistency that is not guaranteed. It doesn't matter if this is on a single machine, a cluster of VMs, or in multiple data-centers.

Comment: @spender, I have added code to my post.

Comment: @spender, I have an extremely hard time grasping the async / await programming. The most i have a grasp on is that async is meant to better use one thread etc. Is it possible to get an example based on the code i have above. I wish to learn it, but find there is a lot of conflicting information about async.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that you have a thread running does not mean that the thread is necessarily consuming 100% clock cycles on a core.  Fire up a diagnostic tool (a process viewer or something) and look at the number of threads on your machine: it will be in the hundreds.  Then look at the total CPU consumption: it will be near zero.  The vast majority of threads spend the vast majority of their time doing nothing but waiting for other things to happen.

On the other hand, if you have a query that takes as long as 5 seconds to execute on your database server, you are in trouble, because it means that you are putting too much stress on it, so the performance of the entire system is going to suffer, regardless of parallelization.

That's all pretty elementary stuff, so if you do not have a grasp of it yet, then it is untimely and impractical to be worried about it.  Just do what you have to do, and worry about performance later.

Comment: Very true. But what you describe sounds like putting each client on their own Thread. Of which i hear may present problems if that number goes up to the hundreds of thousands.

Comment: From the various articles and information online, it seems to be better if i use the ThreadPool style. For the sake of reusing Threads etc.

Comment: Yes, of course you will use a ThreadPool.  I did not suggest putting each client on their own thread.  But if many requests arrive simultaneously, then that many threads will be pulled from the threadpool.  This ***still*** does not mean that these threads will be consuming any CPU.  They will mostly be waiting.  For example, if a thread issues a database request that takes 5 seconds to complete, then this thread will be waiting for 5 seconds.  Forget the threads, your problem is that the 5-second database request will be taxing the database.

Comment: I see your point, I suppose I have alot of learning of proper Socket Async/ThreadPool programming.

Comment: I posted some sudo code in the post. That code, i believe is using ThreadPool because of the AsyncCallbacks etc. I am unsure on how to have these callbacks stop using the thread when waiting for a database to reply. FrindPrimeNumber is the method for the database call for example.

Comment: I told you to stop worrying about the threads.  Why do you insist on the threads?  If you want to be calculating prime numbers on a web server there is no threading strategy that will save you.

Comment: I wish to learn, that's why i insist. The database will be processing, but hopefully, if i can learn the right material, it wont be blocking the thread waiting for the database to respond. Isnt the point of a threadpool for usablity, if i waste the thread, blocking it, that sounds counter-intuitive.

Comment: The point of threadpools is to give programmers the illusion of having unlimited threads at their disposal while spawning only as few threads as actually needed.  The point of threads is to give programmers the illusion of sequential instruction execution while most of the time there is no execution and the thread is just waiting.  So, it is all just constructs for our convenience.

Comment: Async-await is a huge improvement in that it maintains the illusion of sequential execution while not keeping long-running threads active: a thread is only fetched from the pool once an await completes, (in order to run the code following the await,) and the thread is returned to the pool as soon as the next await is encountered.